# What is the difference between PHP Official docker images "apache-bullseye" and "apache" and "apache-buster"

Tags: php, docker

What is the difference between PHP Official docker Images?

- php:apache-bullseye
- php:apache
- php:apache-buster

Comment: Buster (v10) and Bullseye (v11) are both version names of Debian Linux distros; so i would imagine those 2 php images are based on those respective distros. I guess the unnamed third either refers to the most recent of the 2, or to alpine linux (which is commonly used in docker images)

Comment: You can check the "Image hierarchy" of a specific image, by clicking on its tag name, on hub.docker.com. – You can then figure out what specific combination is used for the images you are interested in. I'll update the best answer below, to add this info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Raxi commented correctly, buster and bullseye are the the Debian versions v10 and v11 respectively.
Omitting it by using `php:apache`, it pulls the latest supported version which is bullseye at the time of writting. So php:apache and php:apache-bullseye should be equivalent.

You can check the *"Image hierarchy"* of a specific image, by clicking on its tag name, and see that `bullseye` is a codename for Debian releases, from which the PHP image is derived.
See for example **"Image hierarchy"** at [https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/fpm-bullseye/..](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/fpm-bullseye/images/sha256-e1e3dbc8267588633bbcb5787f4720f5bd71b135fb900cddee9d981717d1be37?context=explore).